# Value is being sent to datalayer, however, the custom dimension is not being caught in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tags

I am experimenting with getting datalayer variables into GA. I am just experimenting so the values are just for testing.

So I paste this link with a datalayer push onto a page:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"
onclick="dataLayer.push({
'test': 'okay'
});">Customize Color</a>
```

I do the necessary configuration in GTM as well as GA.

However, in the debug console of Chrome I get this into the datalayer:

[image: debug console Chrome]

However, this doesn't come into GA custom dimension as you can see below:

[image: debug console Chrome]

One small note, if I paste the datapush directly under the datalayer script, I get the datalayer variable in the custom dimension. However, in that case I do not have a onclick with the URL.

Comment: Can you include screenshots of your GTM tags, variables, and triggers?? It would be good to see how you are trying to acquire this DL variable, and how you are getting that into your tag.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect could be happening is that there is a misalignment when that dataLayer push is being made, and when you are grabbing the value to populate your custom dimensions. You should push an event ALONG with the CD value:

```
dataLayer.push{(
   'event': 'someEvent',
   'test': 'okay'
})
```

and then you should trigger your event tag to fire on the `someEvent` trigger, and at the same time, populate your CD with the `test` value.

EDITS:

Your trigger should be simply this:

[image]

There is absolutely no need to define an `event` variable that's used in an `eventTrigger` that fires on `someEvent`. I believe doing it that way causes issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply! I have tried to change my settings in GTM in correspondence with your post but still got some issues. Maybe I am doing something wrong which could be common sense, but I'm still puzzled. As per request on your first comment: here are my settings in GTM and also the new debug console after I applied your directions/suggestions.

Comment: Debug Console: https://postimg.org/image/79z5q6lzr/
GTM Tag: https://postimg.org/image/6ks6kxu4t/
GTM TRigger: https://postimg.org/image/qvt5fepmj/
event Variable: https://postimg.org/image/qtlj6md2d/

Comment: Last but not least:
test Variable: https://postimg.org/image/s00dfsnjp/

Comment: Hopefully, you see my mistake. In my head it makes so much sense what I am doing. The event tag in GTM pushes the custom dimension test to GA when the trigger condition of event variable is met. And the event variable is attached to the trigger and test variable attached to GA tag in GTM...

Comment: You shouldn't have to define a variable called `event`. In your trigger, you should just go `Event name` = `someEvent` (whatever you're pushing in the dataLayer).

Comment: Days go by fast if you get stuck with a micro-problem.. I think the event name is alligned correctly with GTM as using them as a category or whatever, works fine (i.e. it reaches the field). However, it seems that DL variable values that are pushed to the DL from the page, do not serve well as triggers for tags. maybe it has to do with the lag time as things happens asynchronous... I will have to check. Thanks anyhow, your instructions has at least gotten me a bit further.

Comment: I've updated my answer. There's def some weird stuff going on with your triggering technique. You only need one trigger defined, and that's for the `some-event` event.

Answer (score 0):

Nyuen, great, that was exactly the issue! I didn't see the VALUE of the first declared variable of the datalayer_push also having to be the name of the custom event. I was constantly pairing it in the condition section.... I still don't see the logic of it, but ey, it works! Many thanks!